# Tensorflow:Training doesn't improve accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have just begin to learn tensorflow,and write a model for exercising on MNIST.Thus I am following a book,but there is still porblem,could you please help me about this?

Following is my code with problem description in it,thank you very much!

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,INPUT_NODE],name='input')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,OUTPUT_NODE],name='output')
weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([INPUT_NODE,LAYER1_NODE],stddev=0.1))
biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[LAYER1_NODE]))
weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([LAYER1_NODE,OUTPUT_NODE],stddev=0.1))
biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[OUTPUT_NODE]))
```

the next y = ()...define forward propagating without using moving average model.

```
y = inference(x,None,weights1,biases1,weights2,biases2)
global_step = tf.Variable(0,trainable=False)
variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY,global_step)
variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
```

the next average_y =()...define forward propagating using moving average model.

```
average_y = inference(x,variable_averages,weights1,biases1,weights2,biases2)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y,labels=tf.arg_max(y_,1))
cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARIZATION_RATE)
regularization = regularizer(variable_averages.average(weights1)) +\
                 regularizer(variable_averages.average(weights2))
loss = cross_entropy_mean + regularization
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
    LEARNING_RATE_BASE,                        
    global_step,                                
    mnist.train.num_examples / BATCH_SIZE,      
    LEARNING_RATE_DECAY                        
)
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)
train_op = tf.group(train_step,variables_averages_op)
```

the problem is when I use average_y to calculate the accuracy,it seems like training doesn't help improving at all:

After 0 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.0742

After 1000 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.0924

After 2000 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.0924

When I using y instead of average_y,everything is good.This really confuse me:

After 0 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.0686

After 1000 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.9716

After 2000 training steps, acc in validatation is 0.9768

```
#correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(average_y,1),tf.arg_max(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    validate_feed = {
        x:mnist.validation.images,
        y_:mnist.validation.labels
    }
    test_feed={
        x:mnist.test.images,
        y_:mnist.test.labels
    }
    for i in range(TRAINING_STEPS):
        if i%1000 == 0:
            validate_acc = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=validate_feed)
            print("After %d training steps, acc in validatation is %g"%(i,validate_acc))
        xs,ys = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
        sess.run([train_op,global_step],feed_dict={x:xs,y_:ys})
    test_acc = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict=test_feed)
    print("After %d training steps, acc in test is %g" % (TRAINING_STEPS, test_acc))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet you are training the classification loss with respect to the `y` logits instead of `average_y`, so the inference graph with exponential moving average is actually not trained

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y,labels=tf.arg_max(y_,1))
```

Comment: yeah,I have considered that possibility.But printing it shows that exponential moving average indeed changed.